# Why does the source code of AngularJS have to be in one big file instead of being broken down to a set of small files well modulized

Tags: angularjs, code-organization

I am wondering if there is any reason why the source code of AngularJS must be written in ONE huge file instead of breaking down into a set of files and then combined together to make one distribution file?

Comment: It **is** *"a set of files and then combined together to make one distribution file"* actually.

Comment: It is a set of files, check Github: 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js